# Does "it" refer to **the letter** or **Norway's Ministry of Finance** in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it refer to **the letter** or **Norway's Ministry of Finance**?

"The letter has now been sent to Norway's Ministry of Finance who will conduct their own assessment and will then make a decision following parliamentary deliberations in June 2018. It's unlikely to have an immediate effect on the fixed income market — as **it** does not stipulate that the bank has to sell its existing holdings. But traders think such a move could set a precedent for others in the future and could have negative repercussions for emerging markets and Japan."

Source:https://www.cnbc.com/2017/09/06/the-worlds-biggest-sovereign-wealth-fund-wants-to-change-its-strategy--and-the-effects-could-be-global.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both occurrences of *it* in the paragraph refer to the recently released letter and not the ministry.